# Returning Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> in rust

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have a function in golang -

```golang
func (s *Server) getEnforcer(handle int) (*casbin.Enforcer, error) {
    if _, ok := s.enforcerMap[handle]; ok {
        return s.enforcerMap[handle], nil
    } else {
        return nil, errors.New("enforcer not found")
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement this in rust. I have written this -

```rs
impl Server {
    fn getEnforcer(&mut self, handle: i32) -> Result<Enforcer, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let e: Enforcer = self.enforcerMap[&handle];
        // match ..
    }
}
```

Can't figure out how to handle error.

Comment: What is `enforcerMap`?

Comment: Assuming `enforcerMap` is a `BTreeMap` or `HashMap`, you would do: `self.enforcerMap.get (handle).ok_or (Box::new (Error::new ("enforcer not found")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better yet, return an option because the only possible error is that the index is not present in the map,

so..

```
impl Server {
    pub fn getEnforcer(&self,handle:i32)->Option<&Enforcer> {
        self.enforcerMap.get(&handle)
    }
    pub fn getEnforcerMut(&mut self,handle:i32)->Option<&mut Enforcer> {
        self.enforcerMap.get_mut(&handle)
    }
}
```

however I highly suggest [this link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) and [this link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/)